# Existence of a maximum $\max_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}\times(0,\infty)^2} \Phi(x,y,t,s)$ (related to viscosity solutions in Evans's PDE)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization, maxima-minima

In Evans's PDE (on page 588), in the proof of a uniqueness result for viscosity solutions of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, it is claimed that there exists the maximum

> $$\max_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}\times (0,\infty)^2} \Phi(x,y,t,s) = \max_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}\times (0,\infty)^2} u(x,t) - v(y,s) - \lambda (t+s) - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(|x-y|^2+(t-s)^2) -\epsilon(|x|^2+|y|^2)$$
>   where $\epsilon>0$, $\lambda < 1$ and $u$ and $v$ are bounded and uniformly continuous (and viscosity solutions of an Hamilton-Jacobi equation).

Can you explain to me in detail the following points?

1. *Why does that maximum exist?*
2. *What's the motivation of the penalization terms?*

Comment: The viscosity solutions are bounded. The squared terms with respect to x,y are negative, therefore bounded from above. I'm not sure of the formulation, but I think s is fixed. Therefore the terms depending on t are one that is linear and can increase unboundedly, but it would not happen as you have a quadratic term depending on t that goes to −∞ quadratically. Therefore we can bound this from above. From the quadratic terms on $x$ and $y$, you can see that even if $u(x,t)-v(y,s)$ doesn't attains to it's maximum for every $x,y$, it will thanks to the penalization.

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs Sounds reasonable. Why don't you formalize your reasoning in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be a bound for $|u|$ and $|v|$.
For $R>0$, if $t, s \geq R$ and $|x|^2+|y|^2 \geq R$, you have that
$\Phi(t,s,x,y) \leq 2M - (\lambda + \epsilon)R$, and the r.h.s. goes to $-\infty$ as $R\to +\infty$. Hence there exists $R>0$ such that
$$
\Phi(t,s,x,y) \leq \Phi(0,0,0,0)\qquad
\forall t,s\geq R,\ \forall (x,y):\ |x|^2 + |y|^2\geq R.
$$
In particular, the continuous function $\Phi$ reaches its maximum on the compact set $\{(t,s,x,y):\ t,s\in [0, R],\ |x|^2+|y|^2 \leq R\}$.

This explains the presence of the penalization terms $-\lambda(t+s)$ and $-\epsilon(|x|^2 + |y|^2)$.

The other penalization term
$$
-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} (|x-y|^2 + |t-s|^2)
$$
is a standard term in all the proofs based on the Kruzkov's doubling of variables technique.
Heuristically, you see that as $\epsilon\to 0$ you need to have $|x_\epsilon - y_\epsilon|$ and $|t_\epsilon - s_\epsilon|$ very small at maximum points $(t_\epsilon, s_\epsilon, x_\epsilon, y_\epsilon)$ of $\Phi$.
If you go through Evans' proof, this fact is seen for instance in formula (11).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also have another related question: in these comparison theorems for viscosity solutions we often assume $u(x,0)\ge v(x,0)$ to conclude $u(x,t)\ge v(x,t)$ (as in  https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/HJ-lnotes.pdf on page 19). When is that assumption used?

Comment: At the very beginning. If that condition is not fulfilled, you cannot find a positive $\lambda > 0$ such that (5.26) holds.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: You are right. That condition ensures that you have an internal maximum point (i.e., for every fixed $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, the maximum is achieved for $t_\epsilon, s_\epsilon > 0$ - see the argument in Thm. 5.1).

Comment: I'm not quite clear on that. Would you mind rewriting that argument for the case of Theorem 5.3 (p. 19) in a note to your answer?

Comment: The argument should be similar to Step 3 of the proof of Thm. 5.1, p. 17. If you assume that, for example, $t_\epsilon = 0$, you should get a contradiction.

Comment: Alright. Thnak you.

Comment: I'd like to ask you another very closely related question (so much related that I don't think it should be worth writing a separate MSE question for it): in https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/HJ-lnotes.pdf, page 20, step 3, why do $u-\phi$ attain a maximum at $(t_\epsilon,x_\epsilon)$ and $v-\psi$ a minimum at $(s_\epsilon,y_\epsilon)$?

Comment: The function $\Phi_\epsilon$ attains its maximum at $(t_\epsilon, x_\epsilon, s_\epsilon, y_\epsilon)$; as a consequence, $\Phi_\epsilon(t,x,s_\epsilon, y_\epsilon) \leq \Phi(t_\epsilon, x_\epsilon, s_\epsilon, y_\epsilon)$ for every $(t,x)$.

Comment: This explains that $u-\phi$ has a maximum in $(t_\epsilon,x_\epsilon)$. What about the fact that $v-\psi$ has a minimum in $(s_\epsilon,y_\epsilon)$?

Comment: It's the same. Just fix $(t_\epsilon, x_\epsilon)$ and let $(s,y)$ free.

Comment: Right. Thanks again!

Comment: I've asked a slightly related question you might be interested in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296539/counterexamples-for-uniqueness-of-viscosity-solutions

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume from the notation that $s$ is a fixed value, if it's not, this is not bounded (as a function of $s$).

1) $\Phi(x,y,t,s)$ is bounded from above.

We have that both $u(x,t)$ and $v(y,s)$ are bounded from above.

The term $-\lambda(t+s) - \frac{1}{\epsilon} (t-s)^2$, as a function of $t$, is also bounded from above, as it is a quadratic function where the leading term is associated to a negative value.

The other terms are negative, therefore bounded by $0$ from above.

2) Attains it maximum.

This follows from a general statement. If you have any function $f(x)$ bounded from above that is continuous, then $H(x)=f(x) - c |x|^2$ attains its maximum for any $c>0$.

To see this, you consider the set $A_d=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2: H(x)\geq d \}$ for $d < \sup H(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is bounded from above, this set is bounded. Since $H(x)$ is continuous, this set is closed. Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^d$, this set is compact. Therefore, given that $H(x)$ is continuous, it attains its maximum on any compact set.

Now consider $f(x,y,t) = u(x,t)-v(y,s)-\lambda t - \frac{1}{\epsilon} (|x-y|^2 - (t-s)^2) + \epsilon t^2 $, this will be bounded from above as long as $\epsilon <1$ (if this is not the case, you can find a similar way to formulate this, the idea is the same).

by our proposition, we know that
$$ f(x,y,t) - \epsilon( |(x,y,t)|^2) = f(x,y,t) - \epsilon( |x|^2 + |y|^2 + t^2) = \Phi (x,y,t,s)$$
attains its maximum, that is what we wanted.

About the reasoning behind the penalization, I don't know, I'm not familiar with what is the author trying to achieve.

Comment: $s$ is not fixed. The maximum is taken over $\mathrm{R}^{2n} \times (0,\infty)^\color{red}{2}$ and why are you treating it differently than $t$?

Comment: Oh, I didn't saw the square (for me $t$ and $s$ are equal, I just took one)
In that case, this is clearly not bounded if $\lambda < 0$, just take $s=t \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: What about if $\lambda >0$?

Comment: If lambda > 0, then there is maximum and the proof follows the same reasoning. You can just neglect all the terms that are associated to $s$ and $t$, as they are negative.
Edit: Wait, $t$ and $s$ are not allowed to be $0$ ? That can be a source of problems...

Comment: Why can that be a source of problems?

Comment: because if $\lambda > 0$, excluding $u$ and $v$, this function is maximized when both $t=s=0$ (as the terms associated to these variables are negative). Imagine $u$ and $v$ are constant. Then this has no solution too. Therefore you would need more knowledge on these Hamilton-Jacobi solutions around $t,s = 0$ to conclude the existence of a maxima, I cannot further help you, as I'm not familiar with these equations.