# Counterexamples for uniqueness of viscosity solutions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Recall a classical comparison result for viscosity solutions:

> Let $H:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> 1. continuous
>
> satisfying
>
> 2. $\vert H(t,x,p)-H(t,x,q) \vert \le C \vert p-q \vert$
> 3. $\vert H(t,x,p) - H(s,y,p)\vert \le C(\vert t-s \vert+ \vert x-y \vert)(1+\vert p \vert)$
>
> for some $C>0$. Let $\underline{u},\overline{u}$ bounded and uniformly continuous be sub- and a supersolutions of the Cauchy problem for $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+H(t,x,Du) = 0.$$ If $\underline{u}(0,x) \le \overline{u}(0,x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\underline{u} \le \overline{u}$ in $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n.$

Can you give counterexamples that show that the claim does not hold if we remove any one of assumptions **1** or **2** or remove parts of **3**?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are interpreting viscosity solutions via Ishii's notion of solution when $H$ is discontinuous (where you replace $H$ by its upper and lower semicontinous envelopes in the super and subsolution properties, respectively). In this case consider the PDE (or ODE rather)

$$u'(x) = f(x)$$

where $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational, and $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational. Comparison does not hold for this PDE (any linear function $u(x)=mx+b$ with $0 \leq m \leq 1$ is a viscosity solution in the Ishii sense.

It is possible to prove uniqueness when $H$ is discontinuous, but the discontinuity has to be relatively mild (say, a jump discontinuity along a Lipschitz surface), and other conditions have to be placed on $H$.

Comment: Thanks. What can be said if we keep assumption 1 and  weaken or remove assumptions 2 or 3?

Comment: 2. and 3. can be relaxed to a uniform continuity version and uniqueness still holds. Basically take everything on RHS and apply a continuous increasing function $\omega:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ with $\omega(0)=0$ ($\omega$ is the modulus of continuity). You can look at the book by Bardi and Capuzzo-Dolcetta for results along these lines. As to whether there is a counter example between continuity and uniform continuity, I am not too sure.

Comment: Thanks. Do we need both? I've the feeling I've read somewhere that we can do without 2 or any other assumptions on the dependence of $H$ on $D u$, but that doesn't sound quite right to me.

Comment: When the domain is bounded, you can get rid of 2 completely. Otherwise it is required (as far as I know). 2 is connected to a trick you have to play with the auxiliary function to guarantee its maximum is attained on an unbounded domain.

Comment: 3 is always required and is due to the "doubling of the variables" part of the uniqueness proof.

Comment: To clarify things, could you add to your answer a proof of the result highlighting where exactly each assumption plays a role?

Comment: This requires reproducing the entire comparison principle proof, which is many pages long. I would suggest looking at the standard proof in Evans book, or compare Theorems 3.1 and 6.1 here: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~jwcalder/222BS16/viscosity_solutions.pdf  Theorem 3.1 only requires property 3 since it is on a bounded domain, and Theorem 6.1 uses both 2 and 3 for an unbounded domain.